# Unable to select and/or move controls in WinForm designer

Tags: winforms

I am facing one issue in WinForm. I am unable to select and/or move the controls present in the Form in designer. I checked for LOCK property of all controls (including the Form) and none of them are locked.

What could be the issue here? Spent a lot time there. Can anyone please help me?

Thanks & Regards,
Kunal Chowdhury

Answer (score 1):

If the Infragistics controls are shown in the Component Tray, than there might be version differences. What you could try is to open the licenses.licx file and remove the content from there. Do you have an Infragistics controls installed on your machine? Are there any difference after setting the "Specific Version" property of the Infragistics assemblies to "false"?

Is this happening only in your existing project or the same behavior is reproducible in a new project as well?